# Opening a second presentation fails - Delphi XE2 + Windows 8

Tags: delphi, powerpoint

Need to an open an PowerPoint presentation. I am using the below statement.

Var
   ppt: _Application;
   pres: _Presentation;

```
        try
            ppt := GetActiveOleObject('PowerPoint.Application') as _Application;
        except
            ppt := CreateOleObject('PowerPoint.Application') as _Application ;
        end;

       ppt.Visible := msoTrue;

        try
           pres := ppt.Presentations.Open(FPOTX, msoFalse, msoTrue, msoTrue);
        except
        on e:exception do begin
           printtofile('Error in call to ppt.Presentation.Open' + e.message);
           end;
        end;
```

It works fine whenever , CreateOleObject() in exception is called. (i.e., no presentation is already open).

But the above statement fails , if one presentation is already open. (i.e, ppt.Presentations.Open() is called after GetActiveOleObject() function).

Using Delphi XE2 , MS Office 2013 , Windows 8

This fails only in Windows 8 not in Windows 7.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: -1 "fails" is not a good problem description. And this question seems familiar. Looks like you deleted the previous version and asked again. That's not really how it works here. And at the very least, if you are going to ask again, please don't make us have to work through all the question improvements again, just as we did last time. So please don't make us drag error messages etc. out of you again. We already did that once. Why should we have to do it again?

Comment: @David, you probably mean [`this one`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24326026/960757)...

Comment: @TLama Yes, that's the one. For some reason I could not find it. And I cannot vote to close as a dupe (because it was asked by a different user). So, until somebody writes an answer to one of them, the asker can keep making new accounts and asking new questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where the problem is, if it is your Delphi or Office or Windows version. But this code works no problem in Windows 8.1 x64, Delphi XE2 (32bit target), Office 2007. Unfortunately I do not have Office 2013 to test it.

I don't have any Type LIBs imported in my Delphi. So I tested it just using plain `Variant` types.

If PPT isn't opened, the code opens it. Otherwise it gets the OLE Object. Afterwards the desired Presentation is opened. Works as often as I tested it, no matter if PPT is closed or opened.

```
...

implementation

uses
    ComObj, ActiveX;

const
    msoFalse = TOleEnum(False);
    msoTrue = TOleEnum(True);

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    ppt, pres: Variant;
begin
    ppt := Unassigned;
    pres := Unassigned;
    try
        ppt := GetActiveOleObject('PowerPoint.Application');
    except
        ppt := CreateOleObject('PowerPoint.Application');
    end;

    ppt.Visible := msoTrue;
    try
        pres := ppt.Presentations.Open('C:\Temp\Test.pptx', msoFalse, msoTrue, msoTrue);
    except
        on E:Exception do
            ShowMessage('OOPS');
    end;
end;
```

**EDIT**

I also tested it with an imported PowerPoint Type Lib. And your code works 1:1 here:

```
...

implementation

uses
    ComObj, ActiveX, PowerPoint_TLB;

const
    msoFalse = TOleEnum(False);
    msoTrue = TOleEnum(True);

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    ppt: _Application;
    pres: _Presentation;
begin
    ppt := nil;
    pres := nil;
    try
        ppt := GetActiveOleObject('PowerPoint.Application') as _Application;
    except
        ppt := CreateOleObject('PowerPoint.Application') as _Application;
    end;

    ppt.Visible := msoTrue;
    try
        pres := ppt.Presentations.Open('C:\Temp\Test.pptx', msoFalse, msoTrue,    msoTrue);
    except
        on E:Exception do
            ShowMessage('OOPS');
    end;
end;
```

**SOLUTION FOR OFFICE 2013**

As you already found out: It seems to work with `Office 2013` when changing the `Title` parameter of `ppt.Presentations.Open` to `msoFalse` ==> `ppt.Presentations.Open(FPOTX, msoFalse, msoFalse, msoTrue)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here, I have to use ppt as _Application type and pres as _Presentation type not as variant (as you suggested). Can you tell me work around here. Because, in my application they _Application, _Presentation , _Slide were used to open each slide in the presentation and write on each slide. Since this is an existing code in my application, I cannot change as you suggested.

Comment: Hi Guys, changing the title param as msofalse solved the problem in Win8. i.e., ppt.Presentations.Open(FPOTX, msoFalse, msoFalse, msoTrue)

Comment: I just tested it again but with imported PowerPoint_TLB unit and your initial code from your first post works 1:1 here too. But I'm glad you found the solution working for you. And thanks for posting it here.

Comment: I updated my answer with your solution so people searching for it may find it easier.

Comment: What do you mean by 1:1. I didnt understand?

Comment: That your code from your original post also works unmodified on my system when I'm using PowerPoint Type Lib. I don't have to change the `Untitled` parameter to `msoFalse` to get it working using XE2 and Office 2007. So it seems like the single difference is really just the `Untitled` parameter for Office 2013.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me absolutely without any issues. The problem faced was compatibility issue between the XXX.pot(office 1997-2003) and XXX.potx (office2014). Apart from that everthing was fine.